# How to send an array to a CDI bean, in JSF?

Tags: jsf, cdi, el

I have a voting page, the user can select up to 5 items, I'm storing the votes as an array in javascript. Is it possible to do something like this? #{bean.sendData('/getData()/')}

Where, getData() is a javascript function that returns the array (currently, I'm trying to send the array as a string)

If you have another idea, on how to send the votes to a CDI bean, that would be helpful?

Comment: uhhh... if you don't use ajax, you don't send multiple requests to the webserver. So it looks like you are running into an http://www.xyproblem.info

Comment: Yess, sorry about that, my first post here ... so, can you help me on how to send an array to backed bean? Or, if you have another suggestion?! Thank you.

Comment: I still think you have an xyproblem, since there is rarely a reason to store things explicitly in an array on the client side and send it in one (hidden) field to the server. And since for http everything is a string, a (one) hidden field is all you need, or a generic  'how do I send a value from javascript to a bean. Both have several Q/A on stackoverflow. But I'd like to see a [mcve] with real code to confirm things

Comment: There are many good components available to value bind a selection of elements to a bean. You could start at looking at `h:selectManyCheckbox`.